# diskStorage() not found in nestJs multer file upload

Tags: nestjs, multer

i want use multer in my nestJs application like this:

```
@Post()
@UseInterceptors(
    FileInterceptor('file', {
        storage: diskStorage({
            destination: './files',
        }),
    }),
)
async upload(@Request() req, @Query() query: any, @UploadedFile() file) {
    console.log(file);
}
```

But my IDE (vscode) keeps saying: Cannot find name 'diskStorage' and is not compiling.
I also register the MulterModule on the specified Module (FeatureModule).

I can use

```
@UseInterceptors(
    FileInterceptor('file', { dest: '/data-path'}),
)
```

But i want change the filename for example. For this I need the diskStorage function

What can i do, to resolve the issue?

Comment: Where are you importing `diskStorage` from?

Comment: import is from @nestjs/platform-express and in the @Module({ imports: [MulterModule.register()]  .....

Comment: Shouldn't `diskStorage` come from the `multer` package?

Comment: no, the [docu](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/file-upload#file-upload) says platform-express:

Comment: The Nest module for `mutler` comes from `@nestjs/platform-express`, but that function still comes from `multer`

Comment: @JayMcDoniel thanks for that hint. i got it working with the extra import what you said. `import { diskStorage } from 'multer'; `

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the solution was as described by @JayMcDoniel
An extra import had to be made.

`import { diskStorage } from 'multer';`

With the help of this example, I was able to recreate and solve the whole thing again.
https://github.com/TannerGabriel/Blog/tree/091cbf99bc9409629e1ab717ca8ec405c421d6d4/nest-file-uploading